# Принцип открытости/закрытости

Tags: c#, ооп, solid

Пытаюсь понять принцип открытости/закрытости.

Размышляю над этим примером

Пример плохого кода:

```
public void addButton(string os) 
{
    var creator = new Creator();
    if (os == "linux")
    {
        creator.createLinuxButton();
    }
    else if (os == " windows")
    {
        creator.createWindowsButton();
    }
}
```

Очевидно что при добавлении других os придётся дописывать новые else if и нарушать принцип.
Лучшим выходом будет паттерн абстрактная фабрика.
Однако она не помогает избавиться от  расширения через else if, а лишь переносит эту конструкцию в метод уровнем выше

```
//метод более высокого уровня вызывающий addButton
if (os == "linux") 
{
   var creator = new LinuxCreator();
}
else if (os == "windows")
{
   var creator = new WindowsCreator();
}
addButton(creator);
```

В итоге при добавлении os опять придётся дописывать код в уже созданный метод и добавлять else if, принцип нарушен?

Comment: Ну да, фабрика не избавляет от  надобности писать if'ы)) ну или можно динамически создавать классы в соответствии с чем-то, а эти соответсвия где-то хранить, но эти соответствия всё равно придётся где-то править...

Comment: _принцип нарушен?_ - да.

Comment: Ну если брать open close  по Мартину, то сделать, так скажем, менеджер, который будет создавать (по факту будет единственный метод) и его изменять - вполне себе соответствует определению "должен иметь одну причину для изменения", а вот если всё располагать в методе addButton,  то там этих причин может быть гораздо больше, не только добавление ОС.......

Comment: @aepot почему нарушен? а я не согласен

Comment: @АлексейШиманский потому что OCP предлагает не изменять код класса, а писать новый при появлении новой сущности. То есть расширение (открытость) без изменения кода существующего класса (закрытость).

Comment: @aepot эммм.. удалить текущий и создать новый но с дополнением? :D  что за бред

Comment: @АлексейШиманский этот бред SOLID называется :)

Comment: @aepot нет, это неверное его понимание.  в абстрактной фабрике ты никуда не денешься от ифов и добавления нового при новой сущности.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ща что-нибудь напишу более-менее понятное. :)

Comment: @aepot А удалять текущий менеджер и создавать ровно такой же но с добавленной сущностью, чтобы не изменять текущий - это какое-то странное следованию принципу))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский помимо ифов еще есть поиск по коллекции. Это так, намёк.

Comment: @aepot это я описал в комментарии там выше.... но эту коллекцию ты в любом случае будешь формировать.... либо в этом же классе - что подразумевает изменение......либо в конфиге - что, в любом случае подразумевает знание о классах реализующих......но это уже даже не абстрактная фабрика будет вовсе, а контейнеры и всякие IoC  и рефлексия

Comment: Зачем тут разбираться с одной буквой, если остальные буквы зафейлились уже? Начать лучше с D, а дальше и S и I помогут разобраться с O. Типа мне нужна квадратная кнопка в лифте, а дом либо сгорел, либо еще котлована нет.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский даже в случае IoC придется в composition root строчку добавить, но это не нарушает OCP, так как сам по себе принцип призван избавиться от изменений в коде в "10 местах", а не вообще изменений. Он как раз ведёт всю эту историю к единым точкам компоновки приложения. То есть ветвление конечно может быть, но где-то в одном месте проекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без лишних слов, починить это можно просто если унести код выбора из метода создания кнопки в точку сборки приложения.

Допустим, фабричный метод уже есть, и есть абстракция `Creator` и наследники `WindowsCreator` и `LinuxCreator`, и есть метод создания кнопки, перепишу его немного.

```
public Button CreateButton(string os)
{
    Creator creator = os switch
    {
        "windows" => new WindowsCreator(),
        "linux" => new LinuxCreator(),
        _ => throw new PlatformNotSupportedException()
    };
    return creator.CreateButton();
}
```

---

Чтобы не нарушать OCP, достаточно унести это в единую точку компоновки приложения, например:

```
public class Program
{
    public static Creator GetCreator()
    {
        string os = GetOsType(); // определяет ОС
        return os switch
        {
            "windows" => new WindowsCreator(),
            "linux" => new LinuxCreator(),
            _ => throw new PlatformNotSupportedException()
        };
    }

    // ...
}
```

Тогда метод `CreateButton` и использующие его методы не придется никогда переписывать

```
private readonly Creator _creator = Program.GetCreator();

public Button CreateButton()
{
    return _creator.CreateButton();
}
```

А для поддержки новой ОС потребуется лишь создать еще одну реализацию `Creator` и добавить одну строчку в точку компоновки приложения, например:

```
"macos" => new MacosCreator(),
```

Быстро и просто. Особенно это ощутится, если у вас не только кнопки, а пара сотен других контролов и штук 5 поддерживаемых платформ.

---

И в этом месте вы подходите к изучению шаблона проектирования "инверсия управления" (IoC, Inversion of Control).

Comment: В итоге тут используется та самая фабрика, о которой и шла речь всё это время и которую придётся менять,добавляя новые типы..... Похоже мы изначально друг друга не поняли.... А я, если чесно, думал, что автор именно это  и имел в виду, когда писал про фабрику. Ведь это и подразумевает создание "менеджера" где-либо и использование его внутри

Comment: @АлексейШиманский скорее я изначально затупил, так как моё миропонимание искажено злоупотреблением IoC :)